# Prove for $z$ in the unit disc (real/complex analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Prove for $z$ in the unit disc $$1+\binom{k+1}{1}z+\binom{k+2}{2}z^2+\cdots+\binom{k+n}{n}z^n+\cdots=\frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}\quad(k=0,1,2,\ldots)$$where the coefficients on the left are the binomial coefficients.

I was trying to start with the geometric series $1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^n+\cdots$ and knowing that its power series converges to $\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $|z|<1$. But I do not know where to proceed from there.

Comment: *Hint*: Take the derivative $k$ times.

Comment: You could expand the rhs using taylor series.

Comment: This is a simple [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). The whole idea is to rewrite $\displaystyle{n+k\choose n}$ as $(-1)^n~\displaystyle{-k-1\choose n}.$